# Unable to parse events in grafana annotations

Tags: jenkins, curl, grafana, influxdb

I am working on Grafana for the first time. As a part of learning curve I have started exploring grafana annotations.

I am sending a custom value (build parameter) as an annotated value from Jenkins to Grafana. Here is the command.

```
"%curlPath%" -XPOST "%influxURL%" -H "Authorization: Bearer %gf_token%" --data-binary 'events text="<a href="%BUILD_URL%">%CRN%</a>",tags="jenkins-builds"'
```

It's throwing below error:

```
D:\JenkinsAgentNode\workspace\E2E\anno-test>"C:\Program Files\Git\mingw64\bin\curl.exe" -XPOST "http://xx.xx.xx.xxx:8086/write?db=grafana&precision=n" -H "Authorization: Bearer ****" --data-binary 'events text="<a href="http://xx.xx.xx.xxx:8080/job/E2E/job/anno-test/4/">CR-177-117890</a>",tags="jenkins-builds"' 
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed

  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0
100    61  100    54  100     7  18000   2333 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:-- 30500{"error":"unable to parse ''events': missing fields"}

curl: (3) URL using bad/illegal format or missing URL
```

Please find below screen shot of annotation configuration in grafana.

[image: Grafana Annotations]

I am scratching my head because the same command worked in **Linux** based instance (below command), and I got to see an annotation marking in Grafana.

```
curl -XPOST "http://xx.xx.xx.xxx:8086/write?db=grafana&precision=n" -H "Authorization: Bearer $grafana_api" --data-binary 'events text="<a href="'$BUILD_URL'">'$CRN'</a>",tags="jenkins-builds"'
```

Annotation configuration is same as the above one.

Please guide me where I am committing mistake.

Regards

Answer (score 0):

The solution to highlighted issue is to run curl in **sh** mode instead of **bat** mode in Windows OS.

Hope this helps future readers :)